# XML not showing on Android

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3

I create a query of weather data. Data are loaded as xml.
When the scene is tested in Adobe Animate, all data are loaded.

When the generated apk file is installed on the android phone, no data are loaded

```
villach.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler_vf);
function clickHandler_vf(event: MouseEvent): void {
gotoAndStop(2)
wetter_header.ort_name.text = "Villach"
var wetterloader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var wetterrequest: URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.xml?key=XXXXX&q=Villach&days=1&aqi=no&alerts=no");
wetterrequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
wetterloader.load(wetterrequest);
wetterloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandlerwetter);
function completeHandlerwetter(event: Event): void {
    var xml: XML = XML(wetterloader.data);
    var aktual = xml.current.last_updated;
    var derzeit_temp = xml.current.temp_c
    var max_temp = xml.forecast.forecastday.day.maxtemp_c
    var min_temp = xml.forecast.forecastday.day.mintemp_c
    var wind_max = xml.forecast.forecastday.day.maxwind_kph
    var uv_max = xml.forecast.forecastday.day.uv
    var wettericon = "http:" + xml.forecast.forecastday.day.condition.icon
    wetter_header.version.text = aktual
    temp_derzeit.anzeige.text = derzeit_temp + "ºC"
    temp_max.anzeige.text = max_temp + "ºC"
    temp_min.anzeige.text = min_temp + "ºC"
    wind.anzeige.text = wind_max + " km/h"
    uv.anzeige.text = uv_max
    picloader.source = wettericon
}
}
```

[image: Animate Test]
[image: on Android]

Comment: as you are using HTTP without SSL: try to set up [Network configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) with `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"`

Comment: @Dunraven Can you try querying the server as (secure) **HTTPS** instead of the (non-secure) **HTTP**? Like `https://api.weatherapi.com ....etc`? If still not working then it might be a Android **permissions** issue (_eg:_ there is no permission defined in your APK's `manifest.xml` to allow loading external files, coming from outside of the app).

Comment: Permissions are defined:
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Comment: You'll have to experiment... **(1)** Output an executable for your O.S (_eg:_ on Windows you output as EXE not APK). If the app version running on your desktop O.S can load the XML from **HTTPS** server correctly but the APK fails at same **HTTPS** access then it is definitely an Android Permissions issue. Not sure what extra permissions you need here (no AIR to test code). **(2)** Try using [URL Stream](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html) to read XML file into a bytes Array. Does the Array now have some data when loading is complete?